# Typically, where is the motor/pump of lawn sprinklers located?

Tags: sprinkler-system

My garage has the controls for my sprinkler system. Whenever I turn on the sprinklers, I could hear a motor starting. But I could not for the life of me find that motor. The home's been more than 20 years old, the motor is starting to feel weak. The sprinkler system's pressure is weak. I'm hoping to inspect the motor. Typically, where is the motor/pump of lawn sprinklers located? The control panel in the garage leads to outside of the house like so:

[image]

Comment: Sprinklers generally rely on city pressure. The valves can click or thump. In what area are the sprinklers located ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 they're located in the front and back lawn

Comment: Might be gack in the pipes too - try back-blowing air through the first sprinkler that issues water when you turn them on (first in the chain)

Answer (score 4):

### Follow the wires. Follow the pipes. Follow the sound.

You may have an irrigation well with a pump dedicated to irrigation. Or, it might be some sort of booster pump, from what you describe.

If it's not inside, it might be in a hole/pit outside, (or perhaps under the floor inside?) since I assume you'd already have tried looking in any sheds or similar things outside. Be sure to ventilate well if it's a large pit (3-6 foot diameter concrete cover with a manhole in it - you can die from crawling into those to have a look at the pump if not adequately ventilated.) It might be a smaller pit you can just reach into without climbing in.

In 20 years grass may have grown over the cover. Normally the wires and pipes are not buried very deeply, and if you can't find it by looking and listening, tracing and/or digging down to follow the pipes and wires will lead you to it.

Comment: I've added a photo of where the wires from the control panel lead to (see original post). Does that mean the motor is underground?

Comment: Have you continued to follow the wires? Or to go out to the end of where you know the wires are and listen carefully as the system starts? Where they end up, it must eventually be.